# JSON database module for Ruby/Sinatra? A JS lowDB alternative for Ruby/Sinatra?

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, sinatra

I have to deal with a huge json like this acting as live datasource, is loaded every 5 min from a url..

```
sports: [
{
    id: 200,
    title: "Horse Racing",
    meetings: [ ],
    is_virtual: false,
    events: [...],
    pos: 83
},
{
    id: 600,
    title: "Tennis",
    meetings: [ ],
    is_virtual: false,
    events: [
    {
        id: 301804310,
        is_virtual: false,
        outcomes: [
        {
            id: 32779738900,
            description: "Brown/Pliskova",
        },
        {
            id: 32779738900,
            description: "Brown/Pliskova",
        }]
    }]
}]
```

And need to write methods like

- getAllSports() returning an array object with all sports
- getSport(sport_id) returning the object with this sport id
- getAllEvents(Sport) returning all events list object of this sprot
- getEvent(Sport, event_id) returning events that matches with given event_id
- getOutcomes(Event, outcomes) ... and so on

Is there is a library that parses the json and already have methods some methods to help me to do this kind of stuff? example: obj.find(sport_id)...

In JS you have LowDB https://github.com/typicode/lowdb for this, any similar in Ruby/Sinatra? Or any approach suggestion? Im not using Rails.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use Ruby's built in [JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) library. You would be able to do something like

```
json_string = '{"name": "my name", "age": 5}'

object = JSON.parse(json_string)
object["name"] => "my name"
```

You can then use regular ruby hash / array functions on the returned object. In your case, you could do something along the lines of

```
def getSport(json_object, id)
  json_object["sports"].select { | h | h["id"] == id }.first
end
```

Which, assuming you have already parsed the JSON and passed the resulting value into that function, would return the sport that had the given ID.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if someone has already coded some mothods to findSportByName({name: ''Horse") for example, dealing with a parsed object liek this... , thanks anyway ; )

Comment: The likely hood of anyone having already created something for your specific case is always slim to none. However, with Ruby's general functions, it is easy enough to find the information that you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe not, but who knows. In JS/Node i have LowDB https://github.com/typicode/lowdb it fits perfectly with what I want

Comment: As far as I can tell, lowdb doesn't have the specific functions you are looking for either. The closest thing I can think of would be the `activerecord` gem. Though, I personally think it is too large for simple json parsing and filtering.

Comment: Yes, at the core os lowdb resides lodash collention utils function, may be the question is related with something like this, i will take a look to activeRecord bit it seems a lot, thanks